# Is there a corpus of synonyms that is classified by connotation (or sentiment)?

Tags: synonyms, computing

I am a software developer working on supervised document classification. In this case, a classification system for movie reviews. I need to determine with an acceptable degree of accuracy, whether I am dealing with a positive or negative review. So far I do this by extracting word count and frequency distribution data on already labeled "positive" and "negative" posts.

However, I am trying to test whether using a lexicon would help. The problem is that I lose precision because when I am trying to pull out synonyms I lose the embedded positive or negative connotation of the terms.

Thanks in advance! (bare with me, I am not a native English speaker)

Comment: This is probably [better answered/on-topic on SE main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188706/sentiment-analysis-dictionaries). There are many ways to do sentiment analysis. There are word lists that show positive/negative sentiment. But there are also wordlists that give other connotations to the words. Presumably one could use word vectors  (where nearby words are highly correlated or even synonymous) to help discover sentiment vectors (subtracting off the content/denotation vector  from a word).

Comment: *That movie was sick! I can't get it out of my head* means something completely opposite coming from a 60-year-old and a 20-year-old. You also have people like me who use clichés or sarcasm to indicate boredom or dissatisfaction: *Yeah, that movie was totally awesome. I liked the super-realistic and completely non-predictable battle scene in particular.* (not) Good luck.

Comment: @choster I am not looking for perfect and exact classification. This is basically an statistical problem, I am just trying to improve the system. I would consider such cases to be outliers that I will accept as wrongly labeled by the classifier. However, that "sarcastic" indirect comment can also undergo a feature decomposition that would make it classifiable to a certain extent. For example, you are using an overly emphatic and superlative tone, that is classifiable too.

Comment: @Mitch, yes... I should have researched more in SE. That one is close to the question I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. 'A corpus of synonyms that are classified by ...'. 'A corpus of synonyms that is characterised by ...'.

Comment: @NigelJ not a justification, but consider that I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @DavidCabrera I was not making an adverse comment, only an observation of interest.

Comment: In as compact a form as I can say: On ELU, resource requests and software advice is off-topic (but this is too old to migrate), so I'll answer in a comment. A simple word list has no connotations. A thesaurus will give implicit connotations by the words a word is connected to but is hard to extract the connotation. There exists word lists with simple pos/neg sentiment that might work for a first pass, but words are so much more complex than that (multiple meanings, pos/neg different in different contexts, etc)...

Comment: WordNet is an ontology of informal English word meanings and may be easier to write software with. A word2vec method might be the easiest to get nuances including and beyond pos/neg, but you'd have to figure out which vector is 'pos' by playing around.